# Add 1 week to current date

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got something like this `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yy");` In my code, And I need to add 1 week to it, like `5.4.2012` to become `12.4.2012` I tried to convert it to int and then add it up, but there is a problem when it's up to 30.

Can you tell me some clever way how to do it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You want to leave it as a `DateTime` until you are ready to convert it to a string.

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).ToString("dd.MM.yy");
```

Answer (score 7):

First, always keep the data in it's native type until you are ready to either display it or serialize it (for example, to JSON or to save in a file). You wouldn't convert two `int` variables to strings before adding or multiplying them, so don't do it with dates either.

Staying in the native type has a few advantages, such as storing the `DateTime` internally as 8 bytes, which is smaller than most of the string formats. But the biggest advantage is that the .NET Framework gives you a bunch of built in methods for performing date and time calculations, as well as parsing datetime values from a source string. [The full list can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-2.2).

So your answer becomes:

- Get the current timestamp from `DateTime.Now`. Use `DateTime.Now.Date` if you'd rather use midnight than the current time.
- Use `AddDays(7)` to calculate one week later. Note that this method automatically takes into account rolling over to the next month or year, if applicable. Leap days are also factored in for you.
- Convert the result to a string using your desired format

```cs
// Current local server time + 7 days
DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).ToString("dd.MM.yy");

// Midnight + 7 days
DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(7).ToString("dd.MM.yy");
```

---

And there are plenty of other methods in the framework to help with:

- Internationalization
- UTC and timezones (though you might want to check out [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) for more advanced applications)
- Operator overloading for some basic math calcs
- The `TimeSpan` class for working with time intervals

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you can't use the AddDays method as in

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
```