# add the specified number of days to current date in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I want to add number of days with the current date. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

I want to add 2 days with the current date.

Comment: Do we really deal with "look up the methods on the classes you work with" questions now? One look tghrough all the methods of DateTime will reveal that there is an AddDays method.

Comment: you don't have google or what? btw the below answers are correct.

Comment: Also consider if you need `.Today` instead of `.Now`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string s = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString();
```

**UPDATE**

In answer to your comment

```
string s = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: I don't want show time, So  how can I modify the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) struct. You can use that method to add or substract any amount of days from the current date, like in this sample.

```
DateTime added = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
string s = added.ToString();
```

Or even:

```
DateTime substracted = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
```

Note that if you are only interested in the date, you could use `DateTime.Today` rather than `DateTime.Now` since that will be a little more performant.

A final note on the use of `ToString`: the output of `ToString` may differ when the OS running on uses different cultures. If you intend to process this outputted string later on, I suggest to pass in the desired culture, using [this overload of `ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Did you have to answer this rather than [looking for a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036413/c-sharp-add-1-week-to-current-date)?

Comment: @Rawling: I updated my post to be more informative then the duplicate. I hope this takes away your concerns about the duplicate, since I think it is a poor post.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString();
```